# Updating obsolete tags (javafx vs javafx-2)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Is there a common way to work with obsolete tags?

E.g. tag [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) was created to mark questions about JavaFX 1.x which become obsolete technology. New JavaFX2 is totally not compatible and even uses another language (Java instead of FX Script).

So FX1.3 questions has almost no value for FX2 users. And 99% of new questions tagged [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) are about JavaFX 2 [javafx-2](/questions/tagged/javafx-2).

It it possible batch rename [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) tag to [javafx-1](/questions/tagged/javafx-1) and making [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) tag a synonym of [javafx-2](/questions/tagged/javafx-2)?

Or other common approach for such situations.

Comment: I doubt your 99% number, according to [a search for the javafx tag sorted by 'newest'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx?page=6&sort=newest&pagesize=50), 5+ pages of questions were posted after August 2011 when FX2 was created, and 6+ pages were posted before August 2011 and therefore can't be about [tag:javafx-2].  There are some 588 questions about [tag:javafx], so it's on the high side of a manual retag.  It would help considerably if those older than August 2011 could be converted automatically...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear then I said "99% of new questions". By "new" I meant smth like "this year".

Comment: Ah, my bad - missed the 'new' qualification.

Comment: np, and thanks for suggestion -- if older than August 2011 questions would be autoconverted I can sort the rest manually.

Comment: The ambiguous situation still persists. The recommendation in the tag wiki of [`javafx`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx) is not clear about when the different tags should be used. And moreover, it should also be clear for people who do not read the wiki.