# Is it allowed to use a script to mass retag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, scripts

A few months ago I asked about the possibility of retagging old [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) questions to [javafx-1.3](/questions/tagged/javafx-1.3) (which is obsolete technology) thus allowing the merging of the [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) and [javafx-2](/questions/tagged/javafx-2) tags.

See [Updating obsolete tags (javafx vs javafx-2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135859/updating-obsolete-tags-javafx-vs-javafx-2)

People continue to use wrong the tag and nobody responded to the mentioned question. So I wonder **if it's allowed for me to write and run a script** (for example, [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)) which will retag all old [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) questions?

Or I would be banned for spamming, cheating or hacking activity?

Comment: there's already [such a script](https://gist.github.com/2996477), btw

Comment: thanks, was it tried for large amount of tags?

Comment: while I used it for retagging couple of tags on [su], I did exercise discretion - used it for not more than 10 for every few hours so as to prevent front page flooding. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Site admins have automated processes to do all of this, and regular site users can propose synonyms; have you proposed a tag synonym between the two? The advantage of this route is that it doesn't spam the front page.

However, since there are **zero** javafx-1.3 questions, it doesn't seem to be in huge demand... once the javafx-1.3 tag exists, a synonym can be created.

Note that in all of this I make no comment on whether that is a sensible synonym / substitution : I don't know javafx well enough to comment.

Comment: There is no [tag:javafx-1.3] questions because they are currently marked as [tag:javafx] together with JavaFX2 questions. This is the problem I want to fix. Synonym wouldn't work here as it's needed to retag old [tag:javafx] questions, not all of them.